# Using kableExtra() breaking hyperlinks in my Latex tables

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, kableextra

I'm outputting a table to PDF via Rmarkdown, and I'm trying to add a hyperlink into my table. It works using markdown syntax when I use `kable()`, but when I add any styling using `kableExtra` the hyperlink goes away. Below is an example:

This works:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(x = "[click here](https://google.com)") %>%
  knitr::kable() 
```
````

and gives me a clickable:

[image: working_version]

But when I change to:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(x = "[click here](https://google.com)") %>%
  knitr::kable() %>%
  kableExtra::kable_styling(font_size = 15)
```
````

I lose the hyperlink formatting:

[image: broken_version]

Anyone know how to maintain the hyperlink formatting while adding additional formatting, when going from RMarkdown to PDF? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use the "latex" option and make use `\\href`.

````
```{r}
data.frame(x = "\\href{https://google.com}{Click here}") %>%
  knitr::kable("latex", escape = FALSE) %>%
  kableExtra::kable_styling(font_size = 15)
````

[image]

Comment: Hum, doesn't seem to work within a kable table using the `vitae` package. Maybe a compatibility issue. Otherwise works using `vitae` but outside of the kable.